# getting NullPointerException on activity onCreate

Tags: java, android

I'm getting NullPointerException on activity `onCreate`. Here is the log from PlayStore,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3781)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3943)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2348)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8191)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:584)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1034)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.creativeday.skyhighenglish.activities.ChatActivity.onCreate (ChatActivity.java:468)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8129)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8109)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3750)
```

This is the onCreate method,

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener, ChatAdapter.OnChatClickListener {

...

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        try {
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
            options.transports = new String[]{"websocket"};
            options.upgrade = false;
            mSocket = IO.socket(CHAT_API_URL, options);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "socketCreate: " + e.getMessage());
        }

// <= ChatActivity.java: Line number: 468

        sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        callBtn = findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
        msgBox = findViewById(R.id.msgBox);
        dp = findViewById(R.id.dp);
        backBtn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        menuBtn = findViewById(R.id.menu_btn);
        chatName = findViewById(R.id.chatName);
        statusTxt = findViewById(R.id.statusTxt);
        returnToCallBtn = findViewById(R.id.returnToCallBtn);
        replyBoxCloseBtn = findViewById(R.id.replyToCancelBtn);
        replyToLayout = findViewById(R.id.replyToLayout);
        replyToName = findViewById(R.id.replyToName);
        replyToTxt = findViewById(R.id.replyToTxt);


        backBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        menuBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        returnToCallBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        replyBoxCloseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        dp.setOnClickListener(this);
        chatName.setOnClickListener(this);
        callBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        //long click listener
        callBtn.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(this);
        dbj = new DatabaseJobs();

        //isCallScreenActive is initialised at Application.onCreate
        MyApplication.isCallScreenActive.observe(this, aBoolean -> {
            if (aBoolean) returnToCallBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else returnToCallBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        });


        setUserIDs();
        updateNameAndPhoto();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(friendsName, getLayoutInflater(), this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        msgChangeListener = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                sendTypingStatus(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (typingTimer != null) {
                    typingTimer.cancel();
                    typingTimer.purge();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                typingTimer = new Timer();
                typingTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sendTypingStatus(false);
                    }
                }, 700);
            }
        };
        msgBox.addTextChangedListener(msgChangeListener);

        getFcmToken();
    }
```

I couldn't find anything relevant from the logs. I have one more activity with a similar crash (in a different method triggered from `onCreate`). This code works fine on all of my test devices. But few users get this error.  Does anyone know the root cause of this NPE?

Comment: Which line is `(ChatActivity.java:468)`

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Comment: Line 468 seems to be empty, are you sure you're on the same code/branch as the released build on playstore?

Comment: @Abbas sorry for the confusion, I had some changes in this file. I suspect that the issue is in ```socket.io``` initialization or ```MyApplication.isCallScreenActive``` observer.